# Matrix multiplication of $n$-dimensional matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

While reading matrix algebra, I came across the index notation. The multiplication of two dimensional matrices could be written as
$$(A_{ij})(B_{jk})=(C_{ik}).$$
How do we generalise this notation for $n$ dimensional matrices? Here the index $j$ is shorted because we are using Einstein summation convention. How are these rules generalised to n dimensional matrices? A simple formula would be of great help. 
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This rule already works for $n \times n$ matrices. The index $j$ ranges from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: @knzhou Could you tell me how exactly the formula would look like? I'm trying to prove determinant multiplication using Levi cevitas and index notations, thus I'm very confused. Thanks

Comment: You should put all the details of what you want to do in your question, or otherwise it'll take a lot of back-and-forth. Also, consider asking on Math.SE because that's really a pure math question, even though it does come up in physics classes.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by an *n dimensional matrix*? Do you mean a matrix with $n$ indices i.e. a 3D matrix would be a cuboid $A_{ijk}$? Or do you just mean the usual square matrix with $n$ rows and columns?

Comment: @JohnRennie what I mean is if 3-D, then a cuboidal.

Comment: You might be interested in this http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~christos/TALKS/SIGMOD-07-tutorial/tensor3.pdf

Comment: @SanikaKhadkikar the term *matrix* specifically means an object with two indices, so *matrix multiplication* is only applied to multiplying what you're calling *2D matrices*. Objects with more than two indices are normally referred to as [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) and there is no unique way of multiplying them though the most common use of the term would be the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). That is very different from matrix multiplication though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visualize the multiplication of two matrices (m x n) and (m x l) as follows:

[image]

You just align them along the dimension that is common and take sum product along it. It's clear that if both matrices have the same dimensions ($l=n$), there are actually two ways to multiply them depending on which axis you align.

With this picture in mind, it's easy to imagine how multiplication of higher dimensional matrices (a.k.a. Tensors) might work. There will be many ways to multiply them. You could align one of the lines, or one of the planes (of any dimension) when you do the sum-product.

Answer (score 2):

First you should not talk about matrices, you should rather call these objects tensors.

Similar to matrices there is not "the" way to define a multiplication, however the Einstein notation is widely used and covers some of the possibilities for a tensor-tensor multiplication.  For example two three dimensional tensor could be multiplied in these different ways:
$$
A_{ijk}B_{mnp}=C_{ijkmnp}\\
A_{ijk}B_{kmn}=C_{ijmn}\\
A_{ijk}B_{jkm}=C_{im}\\
A_{ijk}B_{ijk}=C\\
$$
Which yields a $6,4,2$ and $0$ dimensional tensor $C$.

Edit: In order to do this you need to ensure that the matching indices have the same range for both $A$ and $B$.